# J2Mod basic Master and Slave Questions

Tags: java, modbus

I am trying to make a Modbus Slave and Master using `j2mod` (it's version 1.0.6 tho, so that is compatible with another program).

And I do have some general questions about the code I found online.

I have found almost no useful documentation what so ever, so I'm kind of clueless.

**TcpMaster**

```
this.addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

conn = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
        conn.setPort(port);
        conn.connect();

req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest(ref, count);

trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(conn);
        trans.setRequest(req);
        
        trans.execute();
res = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) trans.getResponse();
```

**TcpSlave**

```
spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
spi.addDigitalOut(bitOut);

ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);

addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

listener = new ModbusTCPListener(3);
listener.setPort(port);
listener.setAddress(addr);
listener.setUnit(1);
listener.setListening(true);
listener.run();
```

So right now I'm getting an Illegal Data Address error at trans.execute()
and my questions are:

What exactly are the two parameters on the Request

```
req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest(ref, count);
```

Where do I define the `UnitId` the Master has to access (in the Master class).

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm not too late to share my thoughts on this. I too find J2Mod confusing at times.

For your first question - "What exactly are the two parameters on the Request?":
On a standard Modbus Device data is stored in 4 tables with 9999 values each:

1. Coils (Discrete Output Coils) - they are **read-write** and they are addressed from 0000 to 270E internally. They occupy registers 1-9999 on the Modbus device.
2. Discrete Inputs (Discrete Input Contacts) - they are **read-only** and they are addressed from 0000 to 270E internally. They occupy registers 10001-19999 on the Modbus device.
3. Input Registers (Analog Input Registers) - they are **read-only** and they are addressed from 0000 to 270E internally. They occupy registers 30001-39999 on the Modbus device.
4. Holding Registers (Analog Output Registers) - they are **read-write** and they are addressed from 0000 to 270E internally. They occupy registers 40001-49999 on the Modbus device.

Each **Coil**(1) or **Contact**(2) is 1 bit (1 byte).

Each **Register**(3,4) is 1 word or 16 bits (2 bytes).

Going back to your question, ***ref*** is the contact (in your case) that you want to read. For example, if you want to read the first contact under number 10001, you would pass 0 (as they are addressed 0000-270E internally). The second parameter, ***count***, is the number of contacts (bits) that you want to read. If you only want to read contact 10001 then you can pass 1 (one contact only).

As for your second question, I'm not sure as I don't have much experience with J2mod.

Usually on Modbus TCP/IP you have the MBAP Header which is 7 bytes.

- Transaction ID - 2 bytes
- Protocol ID - 2 bytes (0000 for Modbus)
- Length - 2 bytes - this shows the number of bytes that follow (includes Unit ID)
- Unit ID - 1 byte

I'll have a look on how to set the ID and will get back to you with my findings.

Hope you are making progress!

Comment: First of all thanks for anwering, I kind of solved some of the problems by myself. And I at least am able to read and write coils right now. Your explanation on how the data is stored sure is useful to me though so thanks for that :)