# J2mod reading different value from holding register

Tags: java, modbus, serial-communication

I have successfully connected to my modbusRTU by using j2mod, when i tried to read the value from holding register ranging 40050 to 40054 i always get 28826,28828,28830,28832,28834. I don't know whats this value, please someone help.

```java
 ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null;
       ReadMultipleRegistersRequest req = null;
       ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res = null;

       int unitid = 1; //the unit identifier we will be talking to
       int ref = 40050; //the reference, where to start reading from
       int count = 5; //the count of IR's to read
       int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction

       //4. Open the connection
       try {

           //5. Prepare a request
           req = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);
           req.setUnitID(unitid);
           req.setHeadless();

           //6. Prepare a transaction
           trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
           trans.setRequest(req);

           int k = 0;
           do {
               trans.setTransDelayMS(50);
               trans.execute();
               res = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
               for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {
                   System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));
               }
               k++;
           } while (k < repeat);
           con.close();
           //8. Close the connection
       } catch (ModbusException ex) {
          System.out.print(ex);
       }

please check this code.
```

Comment: Maybe if you post your code and mention what device you're connecting to somebody might be able to help

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code or the responses you see. Modbus registers are just 16 bit integer values. You need to check the manual of your device to translate or scale these values to useful info like temperature or pressure or whatever. What device are you connecting to?

Comment: @MarcosG. I am connecting to serial modbus using RS232 and my concern is 28826,28828,28830,28832,28834 these values are just incremented by 2?

Comment: I see, but what values are you expecting? What is at the end of the RS232 link? A PLC? a sensor? Have you read the manual of that device? For what we know, the values you get can be anything. If I have a PLC with a blank Modbus map I would expect all zeros. But if I define my own Modbus server on a PC I can write registers with whatever values I want. There are probably millions of Modbus devices out there, not just the one you're using.

Comment: I understand and i will check the manual   I thought its java code problem since modbus poll reads and writes perfectly. here, I am expecting 35 (its the value of temperature) in 40050, also the whatever the value its just showing the same value of 28826 in 40050.i am connecting to messung cpu2211 plc.

Comment: OK, now it's more clear. What address value are you using in Modbus Poll? If you want to read address 40050 you would normally have to use `int ref = 49;` instead of your `int ref = 40050;` Are you using 40050 on Modbus Poll and getting good values? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356179/j2mod-basic-master-and-slave-questions) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, Now, I have got some better understanding about registers, I will check with 49 and get back to you. In modbus poll i used 40050 only and am getting required values too

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you're right, Modbus Poll lets you use Modbus addresses. See [here](https://www.modbustools.com/quickstart.html) where it says "Protocol Address: 40011-->10".

Comment: On second thought it looks like you have to write 10 on the input box to read register 40011... Maybe there is an option to use offsets.

Comment: @Marcos thank you so much for your help. Its working properly man.

Comment: great. You're welcome. I'll write an answer in case somebody else stumps into something like this.

Comment: @praveenkumar , do you have any idea how to write float values using J2Mod.. Actually, I need some help.

Comment: @KumarAnilChaurasiya As i see you can't send float values from j2mod, but i can suggest,  if you want to send 23.5 you can send 235 to register, then you divide by 10 using some program in plc.

Comment: @praveenkumar Actually I am not able to any thing.. I think you have done it earlier.. Leave the Float value.. What about the Integer writing..

Comment: can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: int floatResult = Float.floatToIntBits(result);
        
 try {
            writeMultipleRegistersRequest = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(50, new Register[]{
                new SimpleInputRegister(floatResult >>> 16),
                new SimpleInputRegister(floatResult & 0xFFFF)
            });
           writeMultipleRegistersResponse = new WriteMultipleRegistersResponse(50, writeMultipleRegistersRequest);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WriteMultipleRegistersRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: This is my code,                                                                                                   trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);     myregister = new SimpleRegister();                                                               WriteReq = new WriteSingleRegisterRequest();WriteReq.setUnitID(1);
WriteReq.setHeadless();WriteReq.setReference(regno);  //register number
myregister.setValue(value); //value for registerWriteReq.setRegister(myregister);
 trans.setRequest(WriteReq);trans.setTransDelayMS(50);trans.execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your problem turned out to be quite easy to solve: you were just using the wrong offset for the Modbus address you wanted to read.

Modbus holding registers are by convention numbered starting from 40000, but for most libraries this offset is not to be considered.

So to read register referred to as 40011 in the Modbus map of a certain device you have to use index number 10.

By the same logic, to read register 40050 you just have to change the address line in your code:

```
int ref = 49; //the reference, where to start reading from
```